# Access Denied error when trying to access developers.paypal.com as logged in user

Tags: paypal

When I go to https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/ as an anonymous user, I can see the page fine. However, it doesn't seem to work when I am logged in.

Is there something obvious in profile settings I should amend to be able to go to developer.paypal.com and create new REST API application?

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem and found a solution. Just delete complete history of your browser.

For Chrome shortcut key - `Ctrl+H`

and For Mozilla - `Ctrl+Shift+Del`